# threads utilizations with gui applications

Tags: java, swt

i have this code:
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

```
class Sum implements Runnable{

private int a, b;

public Sum(int a, int b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

public void run(){
    System.out.printf("a + b = %d\t", a+b);
}

}

class Multiply implements Runnable{

private int a, b;

public Multiply(int a, int b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

public void run(){
    System.out.printf("a * b = %d\t", a*b);
}

}

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Runnable worker1 = new Sum(2, 3);
        Runnable worker2 = new Multiply(2, 3);

        executor.execute(worker1);
        executor.execute(worker2);

      }

    executor.shutdown();


 }
}
```

if, I replace sum with some text processing operations, and multiply with some updates for the gui, like a phrase is ok and i want to update the gui immediately, is this a correct way to use threads in a gui application?

Comment: No, GUI-updates have to be done on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).

Comment: i use swt, not swing. actually i want to learn and make an app in swt in 2 days. the app must use threads.

Comment: Different name but if you call it EDT or UI-Thread, all UI-Frameworks I know work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads but any access to SWT controls must be done on the single User Interface thread.

You can do this from another thread using `Display.asyncExec` (or `syncExec`) using something like:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      // TODO code to change a control 
   }
});
```

If you try and access a SWT control in a background thread you will get an 'Invalid thread access' error.